# For ubuntu: where to find GIMP XSane plugin?

Tags: plugins, gimp, location

Noobie: I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and GIMP 2.10.30. GIMP does not see my scanner (Brother MFC-J491DW Printer). Told to dowload and install XSane and Gimp plug in. Downloaded and installed XSane but, after exhaustive Google search,  cannot find GIMP Plugin anywhere on the net.

Comment: Does xsane see your scanner?

Comment: Don't know. What do I have to do to find out?

Comment: You can type `xsane` in a terminal window and see what happens.

Comment: Xsane sees it. Gimp does not.

Comment: "You can type xsane in a terminal window and see what happens." Nothing happens.

Comment: If nothing happens, how can you tell that xsane sees your scanner?

Comment: XSane GUI and Xsane terminal are two different functions. GUI APP shows scanner. Typing "XSane" into terminal replies "0 files loaded"  "0 files deleted." You are confusing GUI app with the Gimp plug-in I am seeking which has no GUI.

Comment: I have struggled to find this also in Debian/Ubuntu derivatives, but it is in the Manjaro repositories and installs easy enough. Maybe you need a second OS in order to use things that are missing in the Debian/Ubuntu tree.

Answer (score 0):

Install `sane` which comes with Gimp Plugin instead of `xsane` using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install sane
```

Then download and install the scanner driver (64-bit) for your Brother Multifunction Printer from the following link: https://support.brother.com/g/b/branch/downloadend.aspx?c=it&lang=it&prod=mfcj491dw_us_eu_as&os=128&dlid=dlf105200_000&flang=4&type3=566

Now launch Gimp and you will be able to scan images from within Gimp by selecting *File* → *Create* → *xscanimage*.