# Sane not found in Gimp

Tags: plugins, gimp, sane

I have follodew the tips in [For ubuntu: where to find GIMP XSane plugin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388101/for-ubuntu-where-to-find-gimp-xsane-plugin), but I can't see the *File → Create → xscanimage* menu option.

I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and GIMP 2.10.30. I installed both `sudo apt install xsane` and `sudo apt-get install sane`, and XSane is working.

What should I do to use Gimp for scanning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lubuntu 22.04.1: XSane GIMP Plugin Doesn't Work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427978/lubuntu-22-04-1-xsane-gimp-plugin-doesnt-work)

Comment: Seems to be very similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427978/lubuntu-22-04-1-xsane-gimp-plugin-doesnt-work . I got today ubuntu update (uname -r: 5.15.0-60-generic) but the problem still exists